# Edit part of a line in text without losing other lines

Tags: linux, awk, sed, ex

I tried to replace the `tstop` parameter of the text from `120` to `80`. What I got was a single line of text: `tstop 80`, losing the rest of the text. I used

```
sed -i -rne 's/(tstop)\s+\w+/\1 80/gip'
```

I want to change only the line `tstop` and keep the rest of text as it is.

Part of the text is:

```
[Grid]    
X1-grid    1     -6.0  24 u 6.0  
X2-grid    1     -24.   96 u 24.    
X3-grid    1     -18.0  72 u 18.0    
[Chombo Refinement]   
Levels           4     
Ref_ratio        2 2 2 2 2     
Regrid_interval  2 2 2 2     
Refine_thresh    0.3    
Tag_buffer_size  3    
Block_factor     8    
Max_grid_size    64    
Fill_ratio       0.75    
[Time]    
CFL              0.3    
CFL_max_var      1.1    
tstop            120    
first_dt         1.e-5    
[Solver]    
Solver         tvdlf
```

Comment: You don't need the `g` suffix on the substitute; there'll only be one `tstop` field on the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/^(tstop +)[^ ]*/\180/' file
```

or

```
sed -E '/^tstop/s/[^ ]+$/80/' file
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: This is exactly what I want. I just have 1 question what does means the */\180/  so i understand better how sed works.

Comment: The parentheses `()` mark a capturing group and `\1` means use here the value from first capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

The `n` flag in `-rne` suppresses the normal output of the sed command. Only lines matching your pattern will be output with your `p` command. Try this:

```
sed -i -re 's/(tstop)\s+\w+/\1 80/gi'
```

A more portable version using BRE(Basic Regular Expresssions) could be:

```
sed -i -e 's/\(tstop\)\(  *\)[[:alnum:]]*/\1\280/' file
```

Note that spaces after `tstop` are also captured here, to preserve the file format. Also `i` and `g` modifiers seem to be useless in your case.